# Facebook friend location visited

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a travel portal and I dont know if this functionality is possible. Basically, my site provides information of exciting destination to visit. I want to integrate a function I saw on TripAdvisor...the ability to know which of your friends on facebook have visited that destination. 
If the user is already logged on to facebook, it automatically returns their profile image in a bubble form. If not,it gives them the option to log on to facebook.

I got this idea from TripAdvisor, and wondering if possible.

Thanks for your assistance.

Regards,

Seyi Osinowo

Answer (score 1):

I guess TripAdvisor is using the `/{page-id}.context/friends_tagged_at` endpoint for that. Therefore, you'd need to know the Facebook placeId for the specific destination. Theoretically, you can use the Place Search in conjunction with lat/lng and radius for that:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q=coffee&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page.context/friends_tagged_at
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search

Comment: Tobi, now we’re even with the “I was just gonna say that”, LOL